# Modifying referenced value not the referencing value

Tags: javascript

Here is the code.  It is a insert function for a binary search tree.

```js
    let bst = new class BinarySearchTree {
    constructor() {
        this.root = null; 
    }
    insert(value) {
        let newNode = new Node(value);
        let current = this.root; //this doesn't assign current as a reference, instead it assigns it to null
        let left = (current?.left) ? current.left : null;
        let right = (current?.right) ? current.right : null;
        while (current) {
            current = (newNode.value <= current.value) ? left : right;
            left = (current?.left) ? current.left : null;
            right = (current?.left) ? current.right : null;
        }
        current = newNode; //this line assigns current to reference 
        return current;
    }
```

I use `current` to reference the current node. The problem is when I try to set the value of `current` to the newNode, it doesn't assign the value to what `current` is referencing (I assume because it's not a reference). Instead it sets `current` to reference `newNode`.  Is it possible to set current as an actual reference to `this.root` `which = null`.

This is how insert is called

```
bst.insert(250);
```

here is the class Node:

```
class Node {
    constructor(value) {
        this.value = value;
        this.right = null;
        this.left = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include the code that uses `bst`?  And also the `Node` class?  Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66629680/edit) to include a bit more code so we can understand it.

Comment: Unrelated, but why not just use `current?.left` instead of `(current?.left) ? current.left : null`?

Comment: *"Is it possible to set current as an actual reference"* — No. `x = ...` will never modify whatever was in `x` before.

Comment: It looks like there's no way it will ever insert a root node.  The root is set to null on initialization.  Then since there's no current node, left and right will be set to null.  Then your while loop won't execute since current is still null.  I think you need a special case to insert a root node if you're not going to define it in the constructor.

Comment: @Aplet123 good point!

Comment: @abe Even if I have a special case where I assign newNode to this.root, it will still fail on the first iteration, because left or right will be null and can't be referenced...

Answer (score 0):

```js
    let bst = new class BinarySearchTree {
    constructor() {
        this.root = null; 
    }
    insert(value) {
        let newNode = new Node(value);
        let current = this.root;
        let left = current?.left
        let right = current?.right
        while (current) {
            //your code will never reach here until second call
            current = (newNode.value <= current.value) ? left : right;
            left = (current?.left) ? current.left : null;
            right = (current?.left) ? current.right : null;
        }
        this.root = newNode;//setting current will not effect this.root, so you will not be able to reach current on next call if you not use like this
        return current;
    }
```

Comment: How does this solve the problem?  It only really says what the problem is, but it doesn't give a solution.  Although I'm not sure if the question gave enough information...

Comment: this is not a solution, but he/she can find a way for solution with this

Comment: The only real difference I see is that you changed `current = newNode` to `this.root = newNode`, but I guess if you look at it that way then it's OK.